# Multiple Foreign Keys with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, relation

I have the following setup:

One `matchdays` table with a column called `home_team_id` and one called `visitor_team_id`
and a `team` table.

My Match model looks like this:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :home_team_id
  belongs_to :visitor_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :visitor_team_id
  belongs_to :matchday

  validates :home_team, presence: true
  validates :visitor_team, presence: true
end
```

And the Team model like that:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
  has_many :player
end
```

Now it's getting tricky (at least for me). I'd like to be able to call `team.matches` and get all of the matches for the team. Since every team has home games and also games on the road.

Currently I'm getting a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` Error because it's looking for the `team_id` column in the matches table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, what you need is just a method that returns all games where the current team is playing. This should do the trick:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player

  def matches
    Team.where(home_team_id => self.id, foreign_key => self.id)

    # This line will also work if you want to try it out.
    # Team.where("home_team_id = ?", self.id).where("foreign_key = ?", self.id)
  end
end
```

Happy coding!

Comment: `home = Match.where(:home_team_id => self.id)
    visitor = Match.where(:visitor_team_id => self.id)
    
    return home + visitor` did it. But it feels kinda strange to me